# Error al devolver un valor de un método

Tags: java, excepciones, método

Buenos días estoy tratando de crear un método para leer una tecla y devolver su valor, si no pongo excepciones funciona, pero cuando le pongo las excepciones no devuelve el valor, alguna idea?

```
/**
 * Método para leer la opcion
 */
private static int leerOpcion() throws IOException {

    try {
        InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);
        int dato = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        return dato;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println("Sólo son válidos valores numéricos.");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Error de entrada de datos");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando entra una excepción el resto del código del try ya no se ejecuta por lo que no estas devolviendo nada.

Pon un valor por defecto y devuelvelo en un finally

```
private static int leerOpcion() throws IOException {
    int dato = -1; // -1 es un ejemplo, pon el valor por defecto que necesites
    try {
        InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);
        dato = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println("Sólo son válidos valores numéricos.");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Error de entrada de datos");
    }finally {
        return dato;
    }
}
```

Tambien puedes usar la clase `Scanner`que simplifica un poquillo. Echale un vistazo [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Otra opción sería que el método devolviera un Integer en lugar de int, con lo que podrías devolver null en caso de fallo. Aunque en este caso yo no capturaría la excepción (el método ya tiene un `throws`, en cualquier caso)

Comment: Si, usar ´Integer´ tambien es otra opción, pero salvo casos que lo demanden prefiero usar los tipos primitivos. Con respecto a capturar la excepción yo tambien preferiría propagarla pero me he ceñido al código de la pregunta.

Comment: El comentario era para darle ideas al OP, tu respuesta es más que correcta